# Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) nodepool resizing

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've attempted to resize my nodepools as I've run out of IP's and increasing the vnet size is not an option; After deleting the node pools, the cluster is still trying to retain the old number of nodes. How do I enable the cluster to utilize the new nodepool sizing?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Clear out the replica sets. And you should be good to go.